About the number of solutions of system of non linear equations
I was solving a problem of Lagrange multipliers and faced the following system of non-linear equations:

I managed to find 6 solutions by setting each of the variable to 0 and then playing arround with the others. As you can see, I also used Wolfram Mathematica to check and it gives the exact same 6 solutions I found.
My question is, is there a general way to know how many solutions is there, at least for the case of rational functions? I know that for lower dimensions (like, in the plane) I can graph the corresponding curves to see where they intersect, but for these case given the amount of variables and equations I suspect is not that simple.

tl;dr, It's hard.
There is a general method (for the case of polynomial and rational functions), but it is not suitable for hand calculation.  The general method is to compute a Groebner basis for the ideal generated by the defining polynomials.  The defining polynomials are found from a system of rational equations by clearing denominators (multiplying through by the least common multiple of the denominators appearing in the equation) and subtracting the right-hand side from the left-hand side.  This gives a system of polynomial equations (all with right-hand side zero).
The ideal generated by these polynomials is the set of all possible (finite) sums of polynomial (remembering that constants are polynomials) multiples of the defining polynomials.  Another way to say this is: it is the set of all algebraic expressions that are also equal to zero as a result of the defining polynomials being equal to zero.
If the system has no solutions, the ideal contains $1$.  Since an ideal contains all the (constant or polynomial) multiples of any element of the ideal, this means the entire set of coefficients and all polynomials are equal to zero by applying the defining polynomials as identities.  This is a contradiction (to the unstated assumption that the system has any solutions).
Further progress seems to require constructing a Groebner basis of the ideal.  There are conditions for determining if the set of solutions is finite, but direct implementation is blocked by the impossibility of factoring (general) polynomials of degree greater than $4$.
A problem with any technique for simplifying polynomial systems, including the Groebner basis algorithms (start with Buchberger's algorithm), is intermediate expression swell -- the numbers of digits in the rational coefficients may grow and grow, requiring stupendous storage.  A way around this is the use of regular chains (see the short piece at the link and the longer discussion at the "main article" referenced there).
If the solution set is zero dimensional (a finite set of points), compute a regular chain (the linked text describes how to do that from a Groebner basis).  Once one has a regular chain, the number of solutions is the product of the degrees of the equations.  (Specifically, where the $i^{\text{th}}$ equation depends on the variables $x_1$ through $x_i$, the degree of the $i^{\text{th}}$ equation in the variable $x_i$ is used.)  This might overcount solutions if they don't all have multiplicity $1$.  To address this, use standard methods for squarefree reduction.
Not all solution sets are zero dimensional.  For instance the ideal $\langle y-x^2 \rangle$ has the graph of $y = x^2$ as solution set, which is not a finite set of points.  This case is out of scope for the question (because "counting solutions" doesn't carry much meaning for uncountable sets).  One can still attack such sets as flag varieties or a cylindrical algebraic decomposition.

Tysm, this was pretty useful, I think I understand how to find the Groebner basis following the wiki page you referenced, but i still don't understand how to know the number of solutions knowing the Groebner basis, could you help me with that, please?

@Benjacort : Added a bit more about using RURs to count (upper bound the number of) solutions, a reference to squarefree decomposition to discuss catching and "un-counting" repeated roots, then very inadequate references for what to do when the solution set is not a finite set of points.
